# "IndexError: list index out of range" for word cloud generation using "wordcloud"

Tags: lda, word-cloud

Generating a word cloud from a LDA topic model; I've written my own function. The code I have works correctly, but it seems when I have over 9 topics, it malfunctions with the error in the title. My function is below:

```
def word_cloud(lda_model, stopwords, num_topics, max_words=20):
    cols = [color for name, color in mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS.items()]  # more colors: 'mcolors.XKCD_COLORS'

    cloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords,
                      background_color='white',
                      width=2500,
                      height=1800,
                      max_words=max_words,
                      colormap='tab10',
                      color_func=lambda *args, **kwargs: cols[i],
                      prefer_horizontal=1.0)

    topics = lda_model.show_topics(num_topics=num_topics, formatted=False)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 5, figsize=(20,20), sharex=True, sharey=True) ##Change subplots(X,X) (x by x)depending on number of topics and size of image 

    for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
        fig.add_subplot(ax)
        topic_words = dict(topics[i][1])
        cloud.generate_from_frequencies(topic_words, max_font_size=300)
        plt.gca().imshow(cloud)
        plt.gca().set_title('Topic ' + str(i), fontdict=dict(size=16))
        plt.gca().axis('off')


    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

`stopwords` is my variable for stopwords;
`lda_model` is my LDA model;
`topics`, when generated, looks like:

```
[(0,
  [('vaccine', 0.00010371325),
   ('coronavirus', 0.00010371305),
   ('virus', 0.00010371302),
   ('company', 0.00010371301),
   ('people', 0.000103713006),
   ('year', 0.00010371299),
   ('health', 0.00010371298),
   ('week', 0.00010371298),
   ('month', 0.00010371296),
   ('country', 0.00010371296)]),
 (1,
  [('vaccine', 0.09302008),
   ('company', 0.0256833),
   ('trial', 0.02092878),
   ('pfizer', 0.018989552),
   ('dose', 0.016018579),
   ('people', 0.012570566),
   ('coronavirus', 0.010819701),
   ('result', 0.008305227),
   ('develop', 0.008151217),
   ('receive', 0.008143629)]),
 (2,
  [('virus', 0.039755356),
   ('cell', 0.034203984),
   ('coronavirus', 0.017393898),
   ('spike_protein', 0.01255389),
   ('study', 0.012178959),
   ('researcher', 0.0121112075),
   ('antibodie', 0.011299513),
   ('monkey', 0.010478999),
   ('work', 0.010464183),
   ('scientist', 0.0103354)]),
 (3,
  [('vaccine', 0.040374115),
   ('people', 0.019625131),
   ('coronavirus', 0.010731838),
   ('health', 0.009817394),
   ('year', 0.0073348866),
   ('virus', 0.007240349),
   ('vaccination', 0.006699619),
   ('child', 0.0063658543),
   ('country', 0.006317789),
   ('time', 0.00574958)]),
 (4,
  [('vaccine', 0.02136481),
   ('official', 0.019434752),
   ('intelligence', 0.017549671),
   ('inovio', 0.015069468),
   ('research', 0.0143717835),
   ('steal', 0.011561744),
   ('information', 0.011329846),
   ('effort', 0.010575188),
   ('hacker', 0.010529398),
   ('accord', 0.010038691)]),
 (5,
  [('state', 0.013088651),
   ('case', 0.012361386),
   ('day', 0.011750559),
   ('week', 0.0117468545),
   ('health', 0.010911593),
   ('virus', 0.010588758),
   ('percent', 0.009836332),
   ('people', 0.008846515),
   ('country', 0.00816732),
   ('coronavirus', 0.008079335)]),
 (6,
  [('pharmacopeia', 0.005976637),
   ('endotoxin', 0.0042965137),
   ('crab', 0.0030250896),
   ('eli_lilly', 0.002615809),
   ('horseshoe_crab', 0.0021963185),
   ('bacteria', 0.0021963178),
   ('lonza', 0.0018313751),
   ('toxin', 0.0017762607),
   ('revive', 0.0017762571),
   ('sand', 0.0013561773)]),
 (7,
  [('vaccine', 0.00010371444),
   ('coronavirus', 0.00010371354),
   ('people', 0.00010371353),
   ('virus', 0.000103713355),
   ('company', 0.00010371334),
   ('work', 0.00010371332),
   ('case', 0.0001037133),
   ('health', 0.00010371328),
   ('country', 0.00010371327),
   ('government', 0.00010371327)]),
 (8,
  [('preparation', 0.023896027),
   ('novavax', 0.01758243),
   ('trizzino', 0.005532327),
   ('necessity', 0.0041716252),
   ('athlete', 0.0036399176),
   ('initiate', 0.0027596494),
   ('coaster', 0.0027421003),
   ('roller', 0.0027421003),
   ('pump', 0.0022667595),
   ('rsv', 0.0022667595)])]
```

If I change the number of topics to greater than 9, I have to change the plotting part of the function to accommodate 9 subplots. It seems to break somehow at 10, and I get an error saying "list index out of range". I tried changing the subplot part of the function to just show less than 9 topics (3x3, 4x2, etc.) , and the error doesn't seem to show. I have a feeling there's some setting somewhere that I'm not changing it to allow >10 topics plotted, or it's a dimensional thing, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Error below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23196/807526142.py in <module>
      1 for i in range(0,len(corpus)):
----> 2     word_cloud(lda_model[i], stopwords, num_topics=15, max_words=15)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23196/4222636401.py in word_cloud(lda_model, stopwords, num_topics, max_words)
     19         fig.add_subplot(ax)
     20         topic_words = dict(topics[i][1])
---> 21         cloud.generate_from_frequencies(topic_words, max_font_size=300)
     22         plt.gca().imshow(cloud)
     23         plt.gca().set_title('Topic ' + str(i), fontdict=dict(size=16))

~\Desktop\GDrive\PhDHKU\Python\lda\venv_home\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate_from_frequencies(self, frequencies, max_font_size)
    527             orientations.append(orientation)
    528             font_sizes.append(font_size)
--> 529             colors.append(self.color_func(word, font_size=font_size,
    530                                           position=(x, y),
    531                                           orientation=orientation,

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23196/4222636401.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
      9                       max_words=max_words,
     10                       colormap='tab10',
---> 11                       color_func=lambda *args, **kwargs: cols[i],
     12                       prefer_horizontal=1.0)
     13 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it's because there aren't enough colours in the list `cols`.

Fixed as follows:

```
cols = [color for name, color in mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS.items()] + [color for name, color in mcolors.XKCD_COLORS.items()]
cloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords,
                  background_color='white',
                  width=2500,
                  height=1800,
                  max_words=10,
                  colormap='tab10',
                  color_func=lambda *args, **kwargs: cols[i],
                  prefer_horizontal=1.0)
```